# How to perform case-insensitive sort in Kendo Tree view?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using the below code to sort the value of the tree, it seems like the sorting happens based on CASE.

I am trying to figure out a way to perform case insensitive sorting, can someone please help me?

```
if(sortValue == 'Ascending') {
    $("#groupTree").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.sort({ field: "text", dir: "asc" });
} else if(sortValue == 'Descending') {
    $("#groupTree").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.sort({ field: "text", dir: "desc" });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought of listing a sample code to help others who are in search of a work around to perform case-insensitive sorting when using Kendo datasource.

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  data: [{
    "id":"1237",
    "text":"b",
    "encoded":false,
    "items":[{
      "id":"234",
      "text":"b1",
      "encoded":false,
      "items":[{
        "id":"456",
        "text":"se",
        "encoded":false,
        "items":[{
          "id":"567",
          "text":"BB",
          "encoded":false
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    id: 1,
    // lowercase foo should be after 'text:b' in case-insensitive sort
    text: "foo"
  }],
  schema: {
    parse: function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i].lowerText = data[i].text.toLowerCase();
      }
      return data;
    },
    model: {
      id: "id",
      children: "items"
    }
  },
  sort: { field: "lowerText", dir: "asc" }
});

$("#tree").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: homogeneous
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even that your question says "sort in Kendo Tree View" it actually refers to Kendo DataSource.

Said so, it is not supported **BUT** in KendoUI forums there is solution that might work. Check it [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/how-to-enable-case-insensitive-sorting-on-kendo-ui-grid.aspx)